# How to solve this non-linear differential equation.?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''=-(4x+e^{2y})\cdot(y')^3$$

If there is no $x$ term or no $e^{2y}$ term, then it is easy to solve. But here it includes both of them. Is there a smart substitution to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing the equation as
$$
-\frac{y''}{(y')^3} = 4x + e^{2y},
$$
the key is to notice that the LHS is $x''(y)$. So instead you solve
$$
x''(y) - 4x(y) = e^{2y},
$$
which is a nice linear equation whose solution is
$$
x(y) = C_1e^{-2y}+C_2 e^{2 y} + \frac{y e^{2y}}{4}.
$$
Then apply whatever boundary conditions you have and, if needed, invert to get $y(x)$.

Comment: Very well done!

Comment: A bit more detail: to compute $x''(y)$, one can apply the chain rule $\frac{du}{dy} = \frac{du}{dx} \cdot \frac{dx}{dy}$ a few times, e.g. to $u = y$ and $u = x'(y) = \frac{dx}{dy}$